# Request from React Native to Flywheel Local server is failing

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I have a Wordpress site running in Local by Flywheel, and I'm trying to call its REST API from my react native app. I am able to get to the API response from my browser, but the React Native app is saying there's a Network Error.

The local url, which I'm able to get to in the browser, is `https://electro2.local/wp-json/wp/v2/job-listings/`

I've also tried activating a Flywheel LiveLink but then I get a 429 error.

When I call the API from the live WP site, it works fine.

Is there some kind of problem with the two local servers (RN server and Flywheel server) not knowing about each other? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Does your local site at `https://electro2.local` have a valid signed SSL certificate? Without React Native sending a more specific network error message, that would be my first guess. (Your browser might not care if the certificate is signed, and the app might).

Comment: Thanks, that is probably it. How would I fix this? There's an SSL page on Local by Flywheel, but it just shows the OpenSSL version and lists the certificate, `electro2.local.cert`, which I told my computer to trust so it's marked as "trusted". Is there anything to do about this for RN?